# Можно ли получить список типов, констант, классов из модуля (unit)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Как получить список констант, типов, функций, классов из unit-а?
Есть ли какие-нибудь инструменты для этого?

Нужен именно простой список в текстовый файл.
Что-то типа "Structure" или "Delphi class explorer" только с возможностью вывода во внешний файл.

Comment: Никогда не слышал про такой инструмент. Можно попробовать воспользоваться программой `ModelMaker`, но она платная. Я бы написал простое приложение на основе регулярных выражений для получения такого списка. А вам для чего это? Какую задачу вы хотите этим решить?

Answer (score 1):

Есть сторонние анализаторы Delphi кода. Можно попробовать их заавтоматизировать каким-нибудь образом (через AutoIt).

- [Peganza Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/products.html#PAL) (есть все списки, экспорт в txt)
- [Delphi Unit Dependency Scanner](http://www.easy-ip.net/delphi-unit-dependency-scanner.html) (дерево связей модулей, может быть не совсем то)